# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. while installing Cassandra

Tags: curl, cassandra, repository, ubuntu-16.04, gnupg

I am trying to install Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine. This requires adding keys to Cassandra repository. A step requires me to do the following:
`curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -`
But I'm facing the error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.apache.org port 443: No route to host
```

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

I tried looking for answers but there weren't any related to my issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have network setup correctly on your machine - please check network settings & cables/wifi connection...

GPG complaining because it can't read data & data wasn't fetched by `curl` because of this error `No route to host`...